# Deliver emails outside network, from a server behind router DNS and port forwarding

Tags: debian, dns, postfix, exim, dynamic-dns

I've been trying to configure webserver to deliver emails outside the local network. Server is connected directly to the router and relay on its DNS service, and one of that online service for resolve the dynamic-ip of the router (like no-ip, or dyndns). That way it can be reachable from the outside pointing always to the same ip.

I can't succeed to deliver emails using Postfix or Exim (tried both) outside of local network. I already have excluded that the problem could be related to firewall rules. And I'm starting to believe it is just related to the DNS+no-ip and the dynamic ip address of the server.

I don't have any difficulty on configure mail to send outside on 'normal' Virtual Machines. I Did it for testing the configuration before doing it on production server. And i could easily make it work. But on that server really seems it won't work at all.

Can anybody confirm that the problem is related to the network config of the server:

```
 -Dynamic ip (dhcp)
 -DNS service on router
 -no-ip (for resolve the ip from the outside)
```

Comment: are you sure that it is not delivering, and NOT that is is delivering but the recipient mail server is classifying it as spam since it comes from a dynamic address? do you have SPF or DKIM configured? are you on a residential ISP service where port 25 is blocked by your ISP to prevent spam senders?